# Update an existed application through Google play

Tags: android, google-play

I am now running to a pretty weird situation. Any help, suggest, recommend would be grateful.

- My application APK has been installed through email for few months ago (Not register on Google play).
- Now, I want to publish that App to Google play (Same package, same certification, but version up).

So, my question is:
- Can the previous application be updated by Google play? or this will be treated like another application?

Comment: I think it should update, provided that you update the version number

Comment: It will update. The version code is more important than the download source.

Comment: @AlexandreMartin Thanks. Have you been in this situation before? I just want to make sure 100% :)